# Redmine: What is the sql relationship between projects and contacts (companies)

Tags: mysql, redmine

I have a hard time figuring out the SQL relationship between the companies from the contacts table (where is_company=1) and projects.

The following query works for 95% of the time, but I came to the conclusion that the contacts.first_name is not the relationship to the projects table:

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.name FROM custom_values
        INNER JOIN custom_fields c ON c.id = custom_values.custom_field_id 
        INNER JOIN projects p ON p.id = customized_id
        WHERE custom_values.value LIKE '%{CONTACT_FIRST_NAME}%'
```

Please help.

Comment: Not familiar with redmine but you should be able to see any FKs by issuing a show create table statement from mysql?

Comment: There are not foreign keys. Lot's of relationships are defined in the custom_fields table. Multiple types of foreign keys are stored in the same column structure.

Comment: It would be a bit limiting if a company could only have one employee named Stefan, say.

Comment: The contacts.first name is the company name in Redmine (where is_company=1)